# Ansible: Failed to restart apache2.service: Connection timed out

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I am using **Ansible AWX** to issue a restart command to restart an apache2 service on a host. The `restart` command is contained in a playbook.

```
---
- name: Manage Linux Services
  hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: Restart a linux service
    command: systemctl restart '{{ service_name }}'
    register: result
    ignore_errors: yes

  - name: Show result of task
    debug:
     var: result
```

OR

```
---
- name: Manage Linux Services
  hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: Restart a linux service
    ansible.builtin.service:
      name: '{{ service_name }}'
      state: restarted
    register: result
    ignore_errors: yes

  - name: Show result of task
    debug:
     var: result
```

However, when I run the command, I get the error below:

```
"Failed to restart apache2.service: Connection timed out",
"See system logs and 'systemctl status apache2.service' for details."
```

I have tried to figure out the issue, but no luck yet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I later figured the cause of the issue.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

The restart command requires `sudo` access to run which was missing in my command.

All I have to do was to add the `become: true` command so that I can execute the command with root privileges.

So my playbook looked like this thereafter:

```
---
- name: Manage Linux Services
  hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: Restart a linux service
    command: systemctl restart '{{ service_name }}'
    become: true
    register: result
    ignore_errors: yes

  - name: Show result of task
    debug:
     var: result
```

OR

```
---
- name: Manage Linux Services
  hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: Restart a linux service
    ansible.builtin.service:
      name: '{{ service_name }}'
      state: restarted
    become: true
    register: result
    ignore_errors: yes

  - name: Show result of task
    debug:
     var: result
```

Another way if you want to achieve this on **Ansible AWX** is to tick the **Privilege Escalation** option in the job template.

[image]

If enabled, this runs the selected playbook in the job template as an administrator.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

Restarting a service requires sudo privileges. Besides adding the '**become**' directive, if you would like to prompt for the password, you can do so by passing the **-K** flag (note: uppercase K)

```
$ ansible-playbook myplay.yml -i hosts -u myname --ask-pass -K
```